# how to align the Login link

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot]

Hellow I'm new in this development, can I ask if how to align the Login link, as shown in the image the Login link is placed lower than the other text. Thanks so much.

```css
.headerContainer {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.header1 {
  background-color: #283747;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: .2rem solid gray;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

li.headerLeft {
  float: left;
}

li.headerCenter {
  text-align: center;
}

li.headerRight {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer">
  <ul class="header1">
    <li class="headerLeft">Chat</li>
    <li class="headerCenter">Learn and Be Motivated..</li>
    <li class="headerRight">Login</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696226/css-with-aligned-li-within-a-ul

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
li.headerCenter {
    display: inline-block;
}

.header1 {
    text-align: center;
    //other css
}
```

```css
.headerContainer {
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 width: 100%;
}

.header1 {
 background-color: #283747;
 color: #fff;
 border-bottom: .2rem solid gray;
 padding: 1.5rem;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

li.headerLeft {
 float: left;
}

li.headerCenter {
 display: inline-block;
}

li.headerRight {
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer">
  <ul class="header1">
   <li class="headerLeft">Chat</li>
   <li class="headerCenter">Learn and Be Motivated..</li>
   <li class="headerRight">Login</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: @downvoter i am sorry for you , why down vote when questioner accept it? clear it please.

Comment: why i cant vote UP

Comment: @Jury, you can mark me only.

Comment: This is completely wrong. When you resize the browser, the "login" will jump to next line again. float:right always creates a new-line if there is not enough space to occupy on the right-side of the container. Hence I understand that you suggested using display:inline-block on the preceding sibling. But as soon as the width of the container reduces due to resizing of the browser, the element jumps to next line.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` on `li.headerCenter`,

Or you can use `display:flex` for this. Instead of `float:right.`

`float:right` always creates a **new line**.

```css
.headerContainer {
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 width: 100%;
}

.header1 {
 background-color: #283747;
 color: #fff;
 border-bottom: .2rem solid gray;
 padding: 1.5rem;
 position: relative;
  display:flex; /*add this */
  flex-direction:row;/*add this */
}

li.headerLeft {
 margin-right: auto;/*update this */
}

li.headerCenter {
 text-align: center;
}

li.headerRight {
 margin-left: auto;/*update this */
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer">
  <ul class="header1">
   <li class="headerLeft">Chat</li>
   <li class="headerCenter">Learn and Be Motivated..</li>
   <li class="headerRight">Login</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, all answer is work perfectly on my side, however when i change the fontsize on the li.headerCenter , why the Chat and Link menu is not centered as shown here https://imgur.com/a/AlbHs

Comment: use ` line-height ` to center them vertically.

Comment: i added a line-height in .header1 works perfectly thanks, I'll learn a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have added `display:inline-block` for `headerCenter` class and for `header1` class i have added `text-align:center` which aligns the `inline-block` element to the `center`

```css
.headerContainer {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.header1 {
  background-color: #283747;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: .2rem solid gray;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

li.headerLeft {
  float: left;
}

li.headerCenter {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.headerRight {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContainer">
  <ul class="header1">
    <li class="headerLeft">Chat</li>
    <li class="headerCenter">Learn and Be Motivated..</li>
    <li class="headerRight">Login</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```